# Is this a valid Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra

a friend of mine asked me to look over some questions he was working on for practice, and I came across the question.

Prove the following Boolean expression:

$(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\leftrightarrow((X \lor Y) \leftrightarrow (X \lor Z))$

I can't make head nor tail of it unfortunately, there were some minor typos earlier in the paper so I suspected this was the case, but replacing ($Y\leftrightarrow Z$) in the expression solves nothing, as writing the truth table for $X \lor Y$ and $X \lor Z$ show they are not equivalent regardless. At a loss so any help would be appreciated.

Apologies for not using MathJax, for some reason the logical operators were not converting properly.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to prove.

Comment: This is an issue I'm having. I read the question as prove that X OR (Y≡Z) is equivalent to X OR Y which is equivalent to X OR Z. I'm not sure X OR (Y≡Z) is even valid Boolean, but even if so X OR Y !≡ X OR Z . So the question as written to my best knowledge is either unreadable as Boolean algebra, or is false, which makes it unprovable. I am leaning towards their being a typo at this point but wanted to share here to see if I am just interpreting the expression incorrectly. The question on paper is as I described here, I'd like to link a picture but my reputation is not high enough yet.

Comment: If you read it as $(X or (Y\equiv Z))\equiv((X or Y) \equiv (X or Z))$, it's a tautology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tautology, and we can prove it with [Logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence):

$$\begin{align}
&(X \lor Y) \leftrightarrow (X \lor Z)\\
&\equiv(\neg X \to Y) \leftrightarrow (\neg X \to Z)\tag*{Biconditional equ}\\
&\equiv(\neg X \to Y) \to (\neg X \to Z)\tag*{Apply def.}\\
&\land((\neg X \to Z)\to(\neg X \to Y))\\
&\equiv\neg(X \lor Y) \lor (X \lor Z)\tag*{Conditional equ}\\
&\land(\neg(X \lor Z)\lor(X \lor Y))\\
&\equiv(\neg X \land \neg Y) \lor (X \lor Z)\tag*{De Morgan's law}\\
&\land((\neg X \land \neg Z)\lor(X \lor Y))\\
&\equiv((\neg X \land \neg Y) \lor X) \lor Z)\tag*{Associative law}\\
&\land(((\neg X \land \neg Z)\lor X) \lor Y)\\
&\equiv((\neg X\lor X) \land (\neg Y \lor X)\lor Z)\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\land(((\neg X\lor X) \land (\neg Z\lor X)) \lor Y)\\
&\equiv(\top \land (\neg Y \lor X)\lor Z)\tag*{Negation law}\\
&\land((\top \land (\neg Z\lor X)) \lor Y)\\
&\equiv(X\lor Z\lor \neg Y)\land(X\lor \neg Z\lor Y)\tag*{Identity law}\\
&\equiv X\lor((Z\lor \neg Y)\land(\neg Z\lor Y))\tag*{Distributive law}\\
&\equiv X\lor((\neg Y\lor Z)\land (\neg Z\lor Y))\tag*{Commutative law}\\
&\equiv X\lor((Y\to Z)\land (Z\to Y))\tag*{Conditional equ}\\
&\equiv X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z)\tag*{Apply def.}
\end{align}$$

Now let's consider our statement:
$$\begin{align}
&(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\leftrightarrow((X \lor Y) \leftrightarrow (X \lor Z))\\
&\equiv(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\leftrightarrow(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\tag*{Substitution}\\
&\equiv ((X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\land (X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z)))\tag*{Apply def.}\\
&\lor(\neg(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\land\neg(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z)))\\
&\equiv (X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\lor\neg(X\lor(Y\leftrightarrow Z))\tag*{Identity law}\\
&\equiv\top\tag*{Negation law}\\
\end{align}$$

Hence we proved it's a tautology.

Comment: Thanks you for taking the time to answer, I knew I must have been interpreting the expression wrong. I just had a quick question about the use of the identity law in line 15. I would of thought that $( \top \land (X \lor Y) \lor Z)$ would simplify to $(X \lor Y \lor Z)$ but instead it simplifies to $(X \lor Y' \lor Z)$ . How does the $Y$become a $Y'$? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Detrimental Manx simply forgot to copy the $\neg$ in the two previous lines. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Using $(a \leftrightarrow b) = ab + a'b'$, you only need to show

- $\color{blue}{X+ YZ + Y'Z'} = \color{green}{(X+Y)(X+Z) + (X+Y)'(X+Z)'}$

Now, just some Boolean algebra gives

\begin{eqnarray*} \color{green}{(X+Y)(X+Z) + (X+Y)'(X+Z)'}
& = & XX + XZ + XY + YZ + (X'Y')(X'Z') \\
& \stackrel{aa = a, a+ab=a}{=} & X + YZ + X'Y'Z' \\
& \stackrel{a+ab=a}{=} & X + XY'Z' + YZ + X'Y'Z' \\
& \stackrel{(a+a')b=b}{=} & \color{blue}{X +YZ + Y'Z'}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The proof is very concise as well, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Two-element algebra $\,(\Bbb B\,\,\leftrightarrow\,\,\vee),\, $ where $\,\Bbb B:=(T\,F),\,$ is a commutative ring, where

- $\,T\,$ is the neutral element with respect to
  $\,\leftrightarrow\, $ (think about $\,T\,$ as *zero*),
- $\,F\,$ is the neutral element with respect to $\,\vee\,$
  (think about $\,F\,$ as *one*),
- we have the distributive property of $\,\vee\,$ over $\,\leftrightarrow.\, $

This $\,(\Bbb B\,\,\leftrightarrow\,\,\vee)\, $ algebra is isomorphic
to $\,(\Bbb Z_2\,+\,\cdot).\,$ Now, it is **easy**. 
*Great!*

> ***REMARK:***   The above OP's expression means distributivity.